# Get unique ID records from a List<T> of a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I got the following piece of code:

```
public class Collect
{
     public string name{ get; set; }
     public int id { get; set; }
     public DateTime registerDate { get; set; }
}

public class ControllingMyList
{

    public void prepareList()
    {
        List<Collect> list = new List<Collect>();

        list= loadList();

        //Rest of the opperations
    }
}
```

Considering that my `loadList` method returns for me many duplicated records (`id` variable) I want to get only one record by ID.

The `Distinct()` function seems to be a good solution but if I remember correctly, `Distinct()` filters all the members of the object so just because of a second of difference from "registerDate" variable is considered a criteria to make it distinct, even if its with the same ID.

Comment: By default, `Distinct()` uses the default equality comparer. So overriding `Equals()` and `GethashCoed()` (and ideally implementing `IEquatable<T>` too) should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    var list= loadList();

    list = list 
        .GroupBy(i => i.id)
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

You have several options:

- Use [`DistinctBy()`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) extension method from the MoreLinq project
- Use the `Distinct()` overload that accepts a custom equality comparer, and implement a custom comparer
- Use Linq `GroupBy( x=> x.id)` and then take the first item of each group.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a comparer that uses the id:

```cs
public class idCompare : IEqualityComparer<Collect>
{
    public bool Equals(Collect x, Collect y)
    {
        return Equals(x.id, y.id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Collect obj)
    {
        return obj.id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

....

list.Distinct(new idCompare());
```

Comment: Your GetHashCode is inconsistent with `Equals`, since it doesn't take only `id` into account.  "Implementations are required to ensure that if the Equals method returns true for two objects x and y, then the value returned by the GetHashCode method for x must equal the value returned for y."  In your case, two different but equal objects will have different hash codes.

Comment: @Matthew - In this case it doesn't matter. I can return id.

Answer (score 0):

static List GetUniques(IEnumerable collection, string attribute) where T : Entity

```
    {
        Dictionary<string, bool> tempkvp = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        List<T> uniques = new List<T>();
        List<string> columns = collection.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ConvertAll<string>(x => x.Name.ToLower());
        var property = attribute != null && collection.Count() > 0 && columns.Contains(attribute.ToLower()) ? ViewModelHelpers.GetProperty(collection.FirstOrDefault(), attribute) : null;
        if (property != null)
        {
            foreach (T obj in collection)
            {
                string value = property.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
                if (!(tempkvp.ContainsKey(value)))
                {
                    tempkvp.Add(value, true);
                    uniques.Add(obj);
                }
            }
        }
        return uniques;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Implement `IEquatable<T>` and override Equals and GetHashCode.  You can have those take into account only id.

```
using System;

public class Collect : IEquatable<Collect>
{
     public string name{ get; set; }
     public int id { get; set; }
     public DateTime registerDate { get; set; }

     public bool Equals(Collect other)
     {
         if(other == null)
         {
                return false;
         }
         return this.id == other.id;
     }
}
```

Comment: This breaks equality for objects that have the same id but different values for the rest of the fields (as well as reference equality). In the OP's case, he is better off implementing a specific custom comparer.

Comment: @Ritch, both of those were intended.  However, it is up to the OP if it fits the needs of his application.